# Output List of message routes

Tags: nservicebus

As part of my startup sequence, I am attempting to log the routes that are defined in the configuration.  I see (in the debugger) that what I am looking for is exposed in "StaticMessageRouter.routes".  Is there any way to get programmatic access to these routes?  This would allow me to see (in the log file) which commands/events defined in this service as well as seeing what is in the UnicastBusConfig section in the config file.

Does this make sense? Is there any other way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: You can use Configuration.TypesToScan to get list of types and make a select statement to get those that implement IMessage interface. This will give you the list of all registered messages. You can read the UnicastBusConfig using the usual ConfigurationManager section reading as any other configuration section.

Comment: In our case, we are using the unobtrusive mode, so the messages do not explicitly implement IMessage.  In the case of reading UnicastBusConfig, there are scenarios where there would not be a UnicastBusConfig for the service.  For example, if the service is receiving a command and publishing an event.  In this case, there would be no need for the UnicastBusConfig section, but there are still "routes" defined in the StaticMessageRouter class in the debugger.